# Pick all selectors CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been searching around and couldn't find anything on this. I only found solutions in JavaScript or jQuery.

I want to know if there is any solution for selecting all elements inside a main wrapper? But then I also want to select all spans inside the wrapper with the `:not(:span)`.

I'm trying to build up my knowledge on my CSS abilities and would like to know if this can be achieved?

Example of what I want to achieve: (Not a working example - This is what i have so far)

```css
div#main-content > *{
  color: blue;
}

div#main-content > *:not(:span){
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-content">
  <h1> Hello </h1>
  <p> Second </p>
  <p> Third </p>
  <span> Fourth </span>
  <h3> Fifth </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: "the :not(:span) functionality" — That what? That doesn't appear to be valid CSS. I also don't see how that would help you "select all spans" as it looks like made-up-syntax to do the opposite.

Comment: What are you expecting `:not(:span)` to do? I encourage you to read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)...

Comment: Guys, i'm here to ask a question to help me expand on my CSS by getting to the bottom of my problem. So I could get a professional view on it and them to explain how it should be. It helps people move forward instead of giving negative comments

Comment: @ChrisBeckett — Instead of complaining about so-called negative comments, try reading and answering the questions people are asking you in their efforts to understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno How is this a library recommendation?

Comment: @Quentin Some of the comments have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: This isn't a tutorial site, to have an answer you have to make tries. @Soolie

Comment: @ChrisBeckett — My last comment stands. Stop moaning and help us to help you.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I still don't agree. He was almost right with the answer and with a few tweaks, he'll get there, and that's why he has come here to find the issue with his code and not asking for code directly. He has shown a great effort. 95% to the answer. Not sure why it felt the other way to you. Anyway. :)

Comment: @Marcro Salerno Honestly I dont agree with your comment. He didnt ask for an tutorial what so ever. He was asking why `:not(:span)` wasn't working as expected. He didnt notice he wrote the selector wrong. Ive seen much worser questions getting upvotes.

Comment: @Soolie Thank you for the support. That's exactly what I did.

Comment: @Red Thank you Red.

Comment: No, he didn't try to do it, he just simulated the wanted effect, it's different.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there. Remove the `:` from `:span` and you will select every element that is NOT a span tag. In other words use the selector `div#main-content > *:not(span)`

```css
div#main-content > *{
  color: blue;
}

div#main-content > *:not(span){
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-content">
  <h1> Hello </h1>
  <p> Second </p>
  <p> Third </p>
  <span> Fourth </span>
  <h3> Fifth </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG as if i was that close to the answer! Thank you so much agrm! :)

Comment: Hehe, you beat me with 42 seconds ;)

Comment: @ChrisBeckett We've all been there! Glad to be able to help :o)

Comment: @Red Oh joy! I'm usually the one 42 seconds behind :o)

Comment: Seems like your lucky day then ;)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `:` from the `:span`. Then it will work. The `:` stays for an `:pseudo` element like `:before` or `:checked`, etc.

```css
div#main-content > *{
  color: blue;
}

div#main-content > *:not(span){
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-content">
  <h1> Hello </h1>
  <p> Second </p>
  <p> Third </p>
  <span> Fourth </span>
  <h3> Fifth </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a small note. Since CSS3 the `:` is for pseudo-classes (like `:not` or `:checked`). Pseudo-elements (like `::after` or `::before`) should use a double colon `::`.

Comment: @JordiNebot Good comment.

Answer (score 0):

Inside **:not()** no need to use **:** with selector. so see the attached code for the update.

### Updated code

```css
div#main-content>* {
  color: blue;
}

div#main-content>*:not(span) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-content">
  <h1> Hello </h1>
  <p> Second </p>
  <p> Third </p>
  <span> Fourth </span>
  <h3> Fifth </h3>
</div>
```